# autostart application on raspberry pi 4 (systemd)

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-lite, qt, systemd-startup

I am working with raspberry pi os lite on raspberry pi 4.

I wanted to autostart a Qt application.

I created under `/etc/systemd/system` a .service file named `application_one.service`

this is what the .service file looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Qt application autostart
After=graphical.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/a
ExecStart=/home/pi/a/test_v1 -platform linuxfb

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after that I enabled this service
`sudo systemctl enable application_one.service`

but it couldn't autostart the apllication after rebooting

when I do `sudo systemctl start application_one.service` it works fine

these ares the status

```
sudo systemctl status application_one.service 
● application_one.service - Qt application autostart
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/application_one.service; enabled; vendor 
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

when booting I have 2 messages before splashscreen

`[  3.005162] systemd[1] : multi-user.target : Job application_one.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with multi-user.target/start`

```
[  3.005162] systemd[1] : multi-user.target : Job application_one.service/start 
lti-user.target/start
```

this is what my splashscreen.service looks like :

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fbi -d /dev/fb0 --noverbose -a /home/pi/image.png
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Can some please explain to me what I am doing wrong

thank you

Comment: You crippled the status output and cut important information. Please add the complete output. What shall the graphical program do when running as service in the background? Why is a GUI needed?

Comment: I didn't realy understand what you meant can you please clarify.  I don't know if you are talking about the framebuffer linuxffb , I am using it because I don't have eglfs available, I used to do an autostart using systemd on the same version of OS and with the same configuration  and it worked I don't know why this time it couldn't work. which comptete output? I created a splash screen , so when booting , it shows the splash screen only , the application doesn't start and I got no message or anything

Comment: Please execute this command: `systemctl status application_one.service` and add its **complete** output including CGroup: lines and latest log messages to the question. You use a Qt application that is a GUI library and want to start it after the graphical target. So I assume you are running an application with a graphical user interface. Why do you need a GUI by running `/home/pi/a/test_v1` as service continous in the background? Services do not have a user interface.

Comment: `sudo systemctl status application_one.service 
● application_one.service - Qt application autostart
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/application_one.service; enabled; vendor 
   Active: inactive (dead)
lines 1-3/3 (END) ` this all what I got

Comment: The Qt application contains a dashboard actually it contains only some images and some text but I intend to use some gpio pins with the help of the wiringPi library.  I just wanted to started after the graphical user interface to make sure it will start and there will be no missing dependencies. the  `test_v1` is just an exactable of my Qt application that I want to start. is there an other way to autostart it without using a service?

Comment: What do yo get with `sudo systemctl start application_one.service`? Does `test_v1` stay running in the background or does it successfully finished after a short running?

Comment: with the `sudo systemctl start application_one.service` the `test_v1` runs normally

Comment: sorry I just realized that when booting and before splash screen I got 2 messages : `[  3.005162] systemd[1] : multi-user.target : Job application_one.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with multi-user.target/start` `[  3.005162] systemd[1] : multi-user.target : Job application_one.service/start  lti-user.target/start` I will edit the post and add them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a configuration which is impossible to resolve:

- `application_one.service` must start after `graphical.target` (G before A)
- `graphical.target` requires `multi-user.target` (M before G)
- `multi-user.target` wants to start `application_one.service` (A before M)

One way to break the loop would be swapping the order in which the units load. For instance you have now put `After=multi-user.target` and `WantedBy=graphical.target` in your unit file. Your service will start after `multi-user.target`, but  only if `graphical.target` is about to load. If you want to make sure the GUI is ready when your app is about to load, you may actually want to specify e.g. `After=lightdm.target` instead of `multi-user`.

Comment: Thank you I just verified the order with `systemd-analyze critical-chain` you are right ! but removing `WantedBy=multi-user.target` didn't fix the problem because when I tried to enable the service an error showed up `The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=, Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.` so I just swapped the two elements : `After=multi-user.target ` `WantedBy= graphical.target`. Thank you for helping

Comment: the strange thing is that I used this configuration like 2 mounths ago https://www.interelectronix.com/fr/application-de-lancement-automatique-de-raspberry-pi-4-au-demarrage.html and it worked I don't know how

Comment: @mina Thanks for reporting the issue, I will fix my answer.

Comment: @mina That it works some times and then suddenly no more is respected to the asynchronous (parallel) working of systemd. A very little change in timing to start the services will break the running order if no dependencies set.

Comment: thank you @Ingo for your explanation

Comment: I think I follow most of your explanation, but one question:  **Is `lightdm.target` not included in the Lite distro?** I run my systems on the Lite distro, and I have no `lightdm.target`. I do however, have a `graphical.target`, but no graphics obviously.